# Bubble sort names in ascending order in a structure containing name and marks

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

When I call the function and then display it, the output is same as the input. There is no other error in the program, which should mean taht there is some problem in the function. I'm just a beginner so any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
   char name[30];
   int marks;

   void getinfo()
   {
       cout<< "Enter your name:\n"; cin>>name;
       cout<<"Enter marks:\n"; cin>>marks;
   }

   void showinfo()
   {
       cout<<"\nName: "<<name<<endl;
       cout<<"Marks: "<<marks<<endl<<endl;
   }
};


void bubsort( student S[] , int N)
{
    student Temp;
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<N-1-i;j++)
{
    if(S[j].name>S[j+1].name)
    {
        Temp=S[j];
        S[j]=S[j+1];
        S[j+1]=Temp;
    }
  }
}



int main()
{
    student A[5];
    cout<<" Enter details for 5 students:\n";
    for( int i=0;i<5;i++)
    A[i].getinfo();
    bubsort(A,5); //I used the function
    cout<<" Sorted information:\n";
    for( int j=0;j<5;j++)
    A[j].showinfo();  //result is in the same order as input
}
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn how to step through the code in your debugger so that you can see what's going on.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. Can you give me a link to learn it?

Comment: You haven't said what IDE or toolchain you're using, but usually there is a manual or online help for whatever tools you are using. It's really important to learn how to debug before you get very far with learning how to program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays decays to pointers, so your comparison `S[j].name>S[j+1].name` is comparing *pointers* and not the strings.

If you want to compare string you need to use either [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of character arrays, or use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used strcmp and it runs perfectly :)